# Why can't I unlock the 3 chocolate bars unlocked by a cave sighting?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've seen those rocks a gazillion times, now, and yet there is nothing clickable under a certain tree.  What's up?

Answer (score 4):

After seeing the rocks, the ability to click under the tree shown is activated. However, the cursor **does not show anything clickable**.

Regardless of the text cursor, click on **the correct whitespace** below the tree, and a new screen will be shown.

Comment: @Shannono No problem! Seeing as you're new here at Arqade - you can click the little check mark on my answer to "accept" it, which shows others that it solved your problem.

Comment: i tried that... still wont work. What exactly does "correct whitespace" mean?